# Do classes you import in java have to be saved already in separate files?

Tags: java, import

I have to write an extension code and am confused. Here's what I have:

```
import info.gridworld.actor.Bug
public class ZBug extends Bug
```

With the rest my code below that. I keep getting an error message saying that "the import info cannot be resolved" I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Can you somehow show your file and folder structure? I assume either you didn't save the file Bug.java or it is in a wrong directory.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a **semicolon** at the very least:

```
import info.gridworld.actor.Bug;
```

Then, you may miss some of the dependencies. 
Make sure that the `info.gridworld.actor.Bug` class or the JAR which contains it is in the project's build path.

If it is a Maven project, make sure to include the required `<dependency>`.